# Codeigniter Multilingual website default language url

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I'm using [CodeIgniter 2.1 internationalization i18n](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/CodeIgniter-2.1-internationalization-i18n) for developing a multilingual website with CodeIgniter.

My problem is that when the users enter the website URL for example **"www.example.com"** they are forwarded to **"www.example.com/en/default_controller"**, but I don't want any redirection for my homepage (only for the default language, English).

**So they should stay on www.example.com being shown the default controller in the default language (English)**.

For other languages it's fine to have "www.example.com/fr/default_controller" as the homepage.

Comment: I was under the impression that this should happen by default. According the **[documentation](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/i18n-Multi-language-Library-Helper)** : `if default is dutch and the url is http://domain.com/nl/... the page is redirected to http://domain.com/`

Comment: I got the files from the main website and it works perfectly: http://jeromejaglale.com/doc/php/codeigniter_i18n

Comment: try this repo https://github.com/waqleh/codeigniter-language-in-url-internationalization