# Need solution to make multi-language website using codeigniter, that contents from database should also convert into selected language

Tags: codeigniter, multilingual

I want to implement the option for multi-language on my website. I am using codeigniter framework, and I already implement the codeigniter language library that convert all labels to desire language. But I want my website should also be able to convert the contents from database into desired language.
How can i do that?
Thanks.

Comment: Is there solution other then creating database for each language, and google api. Please share ...

Comment: You can use google translate and you can customise to give better look on site .Check this website : - www.bitofvacation.com

Comment: The only best solution is google translate api. Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look on this tutorial.
[Creating multilingual website using codeigniter](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vv1fouP-oSA)

Comment: I already have this solution. This is only for label placed in website that will change the language. But what about the contents from database.

Comment: have you checked this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19658468/codeigniter-multilingual-website-default-language-url ?

Comment: there is not solution for database contents

Comment: when i created a sited i used different columns for different languages in database and placed content in respective columns

Comment: yes i was thinking like this, to create different database for each language with same content. But I am looking for other solution if some one did this before without change someting in database.

Comment: Yes I know about this. but i also don't want to use any api. I think there is no other solution other then these 2 that you suggest (database with other lang, and API ).

Comment: may be but for that we have to research more.

Comment: Thanks for your effort Imran Qamer.